# Why does my solution think the version os this project is 0.0.0.0, and how to resolve?

Tags: c#, identityserver4

I have a project (IdentityServer4 - I pulled it from GitHub) that I'm referencing from another project. When I try to run the project, I am presented with the following error:

> Error CS1705  Assembly 'IdentityServer4.EntityFramework' with identity '**IdentityServer4.EntityFramework, Version=3.1.3.0**, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f294d0afe402bb2b' uses 'IdentityServer4, Version=3.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f294d0afe402bb2b' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'IdentityServer4' with identity '**IdentityServer4, Version=0.0.0.0**, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f294d0afe402bb2b'

I thought the solution would be to manually set the IdentityServer4 version to 4.0.0.0 in the project properties, but it's not. Doing that does nothing.

The only thing that works is if I manually specify the version in the IdentityServer4 project, in AssemblyInfo.cs, `[assembly: AssemblyVersion("4.0.0.0")]`

But half the time (I don't know why not all the time), I'm presented with this error:

> Error CS0579  Duplicate 'System.Reflection.AssemblyVersionAttribute' attribute    IdentityServer4 1\IdentityServer4.AssemblyInfo.cs   21  Active

And the AssemblyInfo file is rewritten with

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.42000
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

using System;
using System.Reflection;

[assembly: System.Reflection.AssemblyCompanyAttribute("Brock Allen;Dominick Baier")]
[assembly: System.Reflection.AssemblyConfigurationAttribute("Debug")]
[assembly: System.Reflection.AssemblyDescriptionAttribute("OpenID Connect and OAuth 2.0 Framework for ASP.NET Core")]
[assembly: System.Reflection.AssemblyFileVersionAttribute("0.0.0.0")]
[assembly: System.Reflection.AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute("0.0.0-alpha.0.26+6d2fb71321570b26f1cdaa22d5d339cf67373b94")]
[assembly: System.Reflection.AssemblyProductAttribute("IdentityServer4")]
[assembly: System.Reflection.AssemblyTitleAttribute("IdentityServer4")]
[assembly: System.Reflection.AssemblyVersionAttribute("0.0.0.0")]

// Generated by the MSBuild WriteCodeFragment class.
```

**So the questions are:**

-- Why does the dev environment think the IdentityServer4 is version 0.0.0.0, regardless of the version I specify?

-- What is the correct fix for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I remember correctly, IDS4 has a complex build system and provides some Powershell/Bash scripts to correctly build itself the first time.

It is also written in the GitHub repository in their 'How to Build' section:

> IdentityServer is built against the latest ASP.NET Core 3.
>
> - Install the required .NET Core SDK
> - Install Git
> - Run `build.ps1` or `build.sh` in the root of the repo

This will set the versions correctly across all the projects of the solution and should resolve your problem.